# Why column count in gridview is 0 when columns are binded dynamically from datatable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview which show column count 0 when gridview is directly binded to datasource and columns are not defined statically. I am unable to come up with this problem.

I tried this below code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_services.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gv_services.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (row.Cells[i].Controls[0].GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = row.Cells[i].Controls[0] as CheckBox;

                checkBox.Enabled = true;
                //  checkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chck_CheckedChanged);
            }      
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: With `autogeneratedcolumns==true` column-count is always 0. It's by design. But you have not even used the `GridView.Columns` property so it's not clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: actually in place of cells.count I have used columns.count..anybody know how can we solve this????

Comment: above code is not working as well.in actual code inspite of cells.count I used columns.count

Comment: Again, always show the real code as well. What is the problem at all? Show the relevant aspx code too. Where do you need to execute above code?

Comment: I have edited my above code

Comment: Show your full `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` code.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you are trying to loop through gridview rows and enable checkbox based on your conditions

try this code

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in yourgridview.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox myChk = row.FindControl("myControlName") as CheckBox;
            if (myChk != null)
            {
                myChk.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```